# AJAX jQUERY to pass data in POST to codeigniter Controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to pass data to my controller in POST method using AJAX and Jquery.

It looks some thing like this: https://jsfiddle.net/10bhsd2o/
I have bootstrap drop-down that displays records from database.

```
<li class="dropdown">


  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ><a href="#"><?php

foreach($sites as $site)
{

echo "<li class='specialLink' id='$site->site_key'>".$site->site_key."</li>";
}?></a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

Now I want to send the data to my controller,the item i select from dropdown of the `<li></li>` tag.

This is my script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">



    $( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
        var value = this.id;

        var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; 
        alert(url) 
         //get value for throw to controller
        alert(value);  

        $("#specialLink").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", //send with post 
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>", 
                    data: {value:value}, 
                    success:function(data){ 
                    alert(data) 
                    } 
              });
        });
    });


    </script>
```

**HTML GENERATED**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ><a href="#"><li class='specialLink' id='54th-65hy'>54th-65hy</li><li class='specialLink' id='HT45-YT6T'>HT45-YT6T</li></a></li>

  </ul>
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{

    var_dump($_POST);
    print_r($_POST);
    $this->data['subview'] = 'customer/dashboard/index';  
    $this->load->view('customer/_layout_main',$this->data);
}
```

Now my my alerts are correct i get proper url in alert i get proper data in alert.

But in my controller when i do print_r($_POST); i get blank array **WHY? Where am i going wrong?**

Comment: show us your `controller` function

Comment: added the controller @roullie

Comment: get the data by use this code $value=$this->input->post('value');

Comment: i tried that as well @Gopal but did not work

Comment: this was my question on your other post.  Why are you doing `$("#specialLink").submit()`?

Comment: Are you calling function `index` inside your `customer/dashboard/index` since you `print_r` inside that function ?

Comment: typo i think  `echo "<li class='specialLink' id='".$site->site_key ."'>".$site->site_key."</li>";
}?></a></li>`

Comment: @roullie please see the fiddle i have a bootstrap navbar i can not put a form in there so i just want whatever value i select from<li> tage get submitted and sent as POST to controller. Now this code i have got from community only

Comment: Yes @HakanKose is that wrong?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i did that but not getting POST data yet

Comment: also added my html code @roullie please check that

Comment: @Rajin remove other lines inside function `index()` except `print_r($_POST)` to see only that call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `html` markup.  since your looping inside an anchor

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php
          foreach($sites as $site)
          {
            echo "<li class='specialLink' id='$site->site_key'><a href='#'>".$site->site_key."</a></li>";
          }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Then change your `click` function

```
    $( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
        var value = this.id;
        var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; 
        alert(url) 
         //get value for throw to controller
        alert(value); 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", //send with post 
            url: "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>", 
            data: {value:value}, 
            success:function(data){ 
            alert(data) 
            } 
        });
    });
```

I don't know if your using the `index` function for other views but for testing purposes.  Try this first

```
    public function index()
    {
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            var_dump($_POST);
            print_r($_POST);
        }else{
            $this->data['subview'] = 'customer/dashboard/index';  
            $this->load->view('customer/_layout_main',$this->data);
        }
    }
```

Let me know what you get on your 3rd alert

Comment: @PraveenKumar i got it  :)

Comment: now i get three alerts in first i get the url in second i get the item i selected and in third i get all my html data .

Comment: @Rajan try first to changeyour `index` function like the above.. Let me know what you get on your 3rd `alert`

Comment: @rourllie i get an array and in that i have that value as well

Comment: @Rajan so there you have it.. your `$_POST` data.

Comment: because it shown in alert but if i print_r it on browser it empty why

Comment: `$_POST['value']` in your controller.

Comment: php gives me erro Message: Undefined index: value

Comment: put it inside `if(!empty($_POST)){`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104708/discussion-between-rajan-and-roullie).

Comment: your code works in my network tab i get what i want but not on browser why

Comment: yes
in my network when i previe XHR data
i can see the data correctly but not on screen

Comment: you are just using `alert()` on your `data`.

Comment: Then why cant i echo it ??? How will use it for further coding? i want to save that value into session by i dont get anything on browser

Answer (score 1):

You Just Change in You Javascript
You remove `$("#specialLink").submit(function(){` and `});`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">



$( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
    var value = this.id;

    var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; 
    alert(url) 
     //get value for throw to controller
    alert(value);  


        $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", //send with post 
                url: "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>", 
                data: {value:value}, 
                success:function(data){ 
                alert(data) 
                } 
          });

});


</script>
```

Comment: i get a big alert in which all my html data is shown

Comment: your controller's you call view file so that view file html show in alert ,show you remove load view file

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
        var value = this.id;
        var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; 
        alert(url) 
        alert(value); 
    $.post(url,{value:value},function(data){alert(data)});
  });
```

Comment: where can i see the POST data